# UserGroup has many Users. How to get the UserGroup of a User. [MongoMapper] [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

**Works**

Retrieving user from database

```
def login(user_id)
  user = User.where(:user_id => user_id)
end
```

**Does not work**

Retrieve user group of user from database. I tried:

```
user_group = UserGroup.find(user.user_group.id)
```

**CLASSES**

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  plugin MongoMapper::Plugins::IdentityMap

  key :user_id,   String,   :required => true
  key :name,      String,   :required => true

  belongs_to :user_group
end

class UserGroup
  include MongoMapper::Document
  plugin MongoMapper::Plugins::IdentityMap

  key :name,   String,   :required => true

  many :users
end
```

**ERROR**

This is the error I get:

"NoMethodError - undefined method 'user_group' for #:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, "**.where**" returns an array and that was my mistake.

```
user = User.where(:user_id => user_id)
```

So instead of ".where", I used ".find_by_userid".

```
user = User.find_by_user_id(user_id)
```

This is [Dynamic Querying](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/dynamic-querying.html), and it returns one entity which made it possible to do the following:

```
user_group = user.user_group
```